# if($ext == ('zip' || 'png')) { echo "Is it possible ?" }

Tags: php, operators, conditional-statements

I'm currently writing sort of a download manager and I was asking myself if that was possible:

```
if($ext == ('zip' || 'png')) { echo "Is it possible ?" }
```

It returns true everytime, so I guess it's not possible. But do you have an idea about how I could easily do this ? I mean, *not* with plenty of "if" or "switch"...

Thanks anyway ! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you could use `in_array($ext,array('png','zip','another','more'))`

see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: don't no, probably depends on number of times you do it... anyhow, it was the first thing, that popped in my mind :)

Comment: @Minishlink: Both is probably O(n) although parsing the regular expression and building the DFA takes time too.

Comment: Another solution would be to use the extensions as a key for an index. That will be only O(1) (after initialization): `array_key_exists($ext, array_fill_keys(array('png','zip'), null))`.

Comment: I've just done some experiences, I have calculated the execution time of the page 5 times for 1° the in_array solution 2° the regex solution.

 
Here are my results: (in seconds)
1) in_array
(0.073891162872314+0.064849138259888+0.074558973312378+0.064404964447021+0.062700033187866)/5 = 0.0680808544s

2) regex
(0.076596021652222+0.063315153121948+0.071804046630859+0.074262142181396+0.074447154998779)/5 = 0.0720849038s

1<2 : in_array _W0N_ !

So in_array is better in my case.

Comment: Good to know, congratulations! :-)

Comment: @Minishlink Good, although 5 iterations is hardly a benchmark ;)

Answer (score 12):

`if($ext == ('zip' || 'png'))` is doing comparison in the following order -> `('zip' || 'png')`, which because at least one is not null, returns TRUE.  Substitute that in now, `($ext == TRUE)`, which I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that php is just evaluating this the same as it would `($ext)`, which is also true.

`if ( $ext == 'zip' || $ext == 'png' )` will check what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You could go with a [switch-case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
switch($ext)
{ 
  case 'png':
  case 'zip':
       // Will run for both 'png' and 'zip'
       echo "It is possible";
       break;
  default:
       echo "unknown extension!";
       break;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to do the same instructions for every extensions in $ext; so it's very long with this solution... Thank you anyway ! :)

Comment: I don't understand. This switch-case will do exactly what you wanted with your original code. Every time $ext contains either png or zip, "It is possible" will be output.

Comment: @Minishlink It might be longer, but it's VERY easy to maintain. Don't think that short code == better code. It has it's pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions, e.g.

```
if(preg_match("/^(zip|png)$/", $ext) { echo “It is possible!” }
```

Related question: [Checking for file-extensions in PHP with Regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321158)

Comment: Oh godness, I've totally forgotten regex...
Thank you !! =)

Comment: This seems like a poor use of regex, and a poor solution to the current problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(($ext == 'zip') || ($ext == 'png')) { echo "It's possible." }
```

Comment: I've also found this solution, but when I have a lot of extensions it's pretty long to write. Thank you anyway ! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, but what you're doing there is incorrect code.  Here is what you wrote:

```
if($ext == ('zip' || 'png')) { echo "Is it possible ?" }
```

And here is what that translates to in php:

```
if( (if $ext evaluates to true then return true) == ( if 'zip' evaluates to true then return true || if 'png' evaluates to true then return true ) )
```

So, since 'zip' isn't one of the 'empty' or 'false' values defined in php, and neither is 'png' you're basically running this if statement:

```
if($ext == true)
```

Which, if it isn't empty, it does.

What you want is - as previously mentioned:

```
if($ext == 'zip' || $ext == 'png')
```

Answer (score 2):

Tiny advice: PHP uses similar to C boolean-type handling in a sense that actually any non-zero value is considered to be "true" in case of residing in conditional part of if- statement. for example if you would miss '=' symbol in compare construction and type `if($var = "val")` instead of `if($var == "val")` you will always get a true value in that statement, because '=' operator would return as a result of set-operation value from the right part "val" that is by-turn converted to 'true'. so it is better to write the literal in the left part of compare condition `if("val" == $var)` cause in this circumstance you would get an error if you loose one '=' symbol in '==' compare.

so your if-statement have to look like this:
`if('zip' == $ext || 'png' == $ext) { echo "Is it possible ?" }`

also probably it would be better to put 'zip' and 'png' literals in constants with names FILE_TYPE_ZIP, FILE_TYPE_PNG or define some enumerated-entity like global PHP-array that resides at the top of your source-page or probably even create some separate class SupportedFileTypes in external file that would emphasize supported file types of your program (in that case check out [PHP and Enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254514/php-and-enums) for details).

at the start of developing the question of performance doesn't have to bother you cause it is crucial to write code that is easy to read and evolve/optimize in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array($ext, array('png', 'zip'))) {
    echo "Is it possible ?"
}
```

The array could be stored somewhere, if you need it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply :

```
if($ext == 'zip' || $ext == 'png') 
{ 
   echo "It's possible";
}
```