# ls -l grep 'keyword' and get result into php var

Tags: php, bash

```
root@ubuntu:/srv/www/web.domain.com/public_html# ls -l | grep 'aria2'
-rw-r--r--   1 nginx nginx      201 Aug 26 14:40 M010102.aria2
-rw-r--r--   1 nginx nginx     1313 Aug 26 14:41 [Heido] Hamasaki.aria2
-rw-r--r--   1 nginx nginx      125 Aug 26 14:41 [Riycou] K-Project [MP4 AAC 720p].aria2
```

I did the following

```
ls -l | grep 'aria2'
```

I wanna do this at PHP, i will probably

```
shell_exec("ls -l | grep 'aria2');
```

Problem is how do I record the return result into a php array

M010102.aria2
[Heido] Hamasaki.aria2
[Heido] Hamasaki.aria2

**Thanks!!**

Comment: what about elementary first step: RTFM on `shell_exec()`?

Comment: You could try http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and use 2nd argument as return array

Comment: why not just preg_split the result string by the line break or a regex that accounts for the spaces between the first 8 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use PHP's [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)? It will return you an array of files:

```
$files = glob('*.aria2');
```

This is roughly the equivalent of the shell command `ls *.aria2`.

By the way, as a general piece of advice, parsing `ls` (by piping it to `grep`, for example) [is frowned upon](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 4):

As per the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) for `shell_exec`, the output is the return value of the function:

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

---

RichardBernards' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508717/ls-l-grep-keyword-and-get-result-into-php-var#comment39819778_25508791) is correct. If you wish to have the output as an array, you can use the `exec($command, &$output)` function instead. Read the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for further information.

Comment: I think shell_exec returns a string... exec() however returns an array with rows for array-items

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP commands to accomplish the same thing:

```
<?php
$directory = getcwd();
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
$result = preg_grep("/^.*\.aria2$/i",$scanned_directory);
foreach ($result as $value){
        echo $value,'<br>';
}
?>
```

More details:

[Checking for file-extensions in PHP with Regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321158/checking-for-file-extensions-in-php-with-regular-expressions)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php